# timestamps() de Laravel - Error horario

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.8 y hasta ayer todo iba bien, pero hoy, la columna "created_at" de cualquier tabla en la base de datos, al añadir un nuevo registro me cuenta 2 horas menos.

Por ejemplo, he añadido un registro a la tabla "categorias" a las 18:03, y el created_at almacena las 16:03.

Esto me empezó a ocurrir de repente hoy, tanto en mi equipo local como en el servidor, siendo completamente independientes.

¿A qué se debe y como puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Configura la zona horaria en el config de laravel

Comment: si alguna de las respuesta que te dieron responde tu duda recuerda marcarla como respondida/resuelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede deber a dos cosas:

1. La configuración de laravel y la zona horaria.
2. A la zona horaria establecida en el Servidor que alberga tu sitio.